# What is the cause of "internal scratches" in my lenses?

Tags: lens

I've got a Canon 50mm with some internal scratches. This has happend me with a microscope eyepice too.

They are like veins but can't be seen in the final image.

Does anyone know what is the possible cause?

(I'll try to post an image but it's quite difficult to photograph)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are describing sounds more like the beginnings of fungus growing on the internal elements of your lenses than scratches. This [article](http://www.truetex.com/lens_fungus.htm) has a lot of information about lens fungus and what causes it. The spores are present in nature. High humidity and warmer temperatures, along with dust as a nutritional source, will encourage the growth of fungus. Here is [another good article](http://www.redbubble.com/people/profaudio/journal/5799370-what-is-lens-fungus-can-it-really-affect-my-camera-gear) about the importance of checking your lenses regularly and dealing with fungus problems as quickly as possible to minimize the chance of permanent etching of the coatings of the elements of your lenses.

[image]